# Converting javascript function to PHP

Tags: php, javascript, function

i'm trying to convert this function:

```
function txt(str){
 var t=''; var s=unescape(str);
 var x=Math.round(Math.sqrt(16));
 for(var i=0;i<s.length;i++) t+=
  String.fromCharCode(s.charCodeAt(i)^(i%2?x:0));
 document.write(t.replace(/\*/g,'<\/td><td>').replace(/\^/g,'" title="').replace(/~/g,'<\/td><\/tr><tr class="dbeven"><td>').replace(/!/g,'<\/td><\/tr><tr class="dbodd"><td>').
  replace(/\|/g,'<\/td><td><a href="\/cgi-bin\/shdb\.pl\?key=')
 );
}
```

to php, this is what I've tried:

```
function Txt($str)
{
   $t = '';
   $s = urldecode($str);
   $x = round(sqrt(16));
   for($i=0;$i<count($str);$i++)
   {
       $t = $t . chr(charCodeAt($str, ($i^($i%2?x:0))));
       $t = str_replace("\*", '</td><td>', $t);
       $t = str_replace("\^", '" title="', $t);
       $t = str_replace("~", '</td></tr><tr class="dbeven"><td>', $t);
       $t = str_replace("!", '</td></tr><tr class="dbodd"><td>', $t);
       $t = str_replace("\|", '</td><td><a href="/cgi-bin/shdb.pl?key=', $t);
   }
   echo $t;
}

function charCodeAt($str, $i){
  return ord(substr($str, $i, 1));
}
```

But it isn't working. Can someone help me?
thanks

Comment: What do you mean by *It isn't working*? Is the output not what you expected? Does it crash? Do you get any error messages?

Comment: What do you expect and what do you get?

Comment: You can replace `substr($str, $i, 1)` with `$str[$i]`

Comment: Due to being lazy I can't be bothered to figure out what function txt does.  Maybe you should explain it.  And name it better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have mistakes in your `str_replace()`. You must replace `*`, `^`, `|` chars, not `\*`, `\^`, `\|`. `\` is an escape character in regular expressions

Comment: how did you use str_split? you should have used strlen instead of count in your for loop. Can't see more places where you try to access string as an array